# Passing array of info into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have the following form which sends each field in the form in an email to someone. However I wish to store the fields into the database and link each order to a sales rep (Which I have set up)  Am I supposed to create a another table for order_details for example to store this.  Pease help[image]

Comment: Quite hard to answer your question as it is not 100% clear what you want to achieve. What kind of objects do you have and how are they related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends how you want to structure your data. There is no silver bullet solution. But I would make three tables. SALES_REPRESENTATIVE, ORDER and ORDER_DETAILS. A sales representative has orders and an order has order details.

So based on your input.

If you have a table with product definitions you might have a product called Coca-Cola and another one Fanta together with their unit price.

The table of order details could then contain a link to the product table and specifying the quantity.

The order table would have a link to the order details for that order with for example also the date of when it was ordered.

The sales representative may then have a link to all orders that relate to him.

Concrete example:

```
PRODUCTS table
Id Name         Price in $
1  Coca-cola    1.00
2  Fanta        1.10

ORDER_DETAILS
Id Order_Id Product_Id Quantity
1  1        1          10        // meaning this order detail is 10 Coca-cola's
2  1        2          20        // meaning this order detail is 20 Fanta's (because the tast is better :))
3  2        2          10        // meaning this order detail is 10 Fanta's
//Here Order_id is a foreign key to the Column Id of Table ORDERS
//And Product_id is a foreign key to the Column Id of the Table PRODUCTS

ORDERS
Id Sales_Representative_Id Order_Date
1  2                       10/17/2014  // Order one made by Luke on 17th october 2014
2  1                       10/19/2014  // Order two made by Anna on 19th october 2014
//Here Sales_Representative_id is a foreign key to the Column Id of Table SALES_REPRESENTATIVES

SALES_REPRESENTATIVES
Id Name
1  Anna
2  Luke
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  I have a table for "salesReps", "orders" and "orderDetails" and I know I have to link ids to pull the relevant information.....correct?  So in the orderDetails table to I store all of the rows from the form or just the prouct ids?

Comment: In the orderDetails you store which products are in the order and a quantity per type of product. Maybe you need a Product table too with product definitions. I will add some info about that in my answer.

Comment: This is so clear to me now.  Thank you soo much for all the help I will let you know Juru how I get on!

Comment: Please flag the answer as satisfying. Good luck with the implementation!